# Compiling ROS Kinetec from source fails when building image_proc

Tags: ros, image-pipeline, opencv3, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using an Arch machine and trying to compile ROS desktop full from source. The build fails when image_proc is trying to link executable.

Here is the error log:

```
[ 23%] Built target image_proc_gencfg
[ 84%] Built target image_proc
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable /home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_proc/lib/image_proc/image_proc
/home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libopencv_viz3.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `vtkSTLReader::New()'
/home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libopencv_viz3.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `vtkOBJReader::New()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/image_proc_exe.dir/build.make:219: /home/alphayed/ROS/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/image_proc/lib/image_proc/image_proc] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/image_proc_exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:139: all] Error 2
```

I think the problem is related to opencv3. I removed it from the system and recompiled it from source but that didn't solve the issue. Can you please help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250846/compiling-ros-kinetec-from-source-fails-when-building-image_proc/) by [alphayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28904/alphayed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

modify `opencv3/cmake/OpenCVDetectVTK.cmake`, for every `find_package(VTK QUIET COMPONENTS ...` add an entry `vtkIOGeometry`

This works for me

---

Originally posted by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) with karma: 143 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alphayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28904/alphayed/) on 2017-01-09**:
Thank you, that worked. Can you please explain what this fix does if you don't mind?

**Comment by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on 2017-01-09**:
I suppose `vtk` has changed its structure in the new version, e.g. move `vtkOBJReader` into a sub library `vtkIOGeometry`, so you have to tell cmake to find `vtkIOGeometry` if you want to use that class.

Arch always uses the newest, that's why you'll encounter such issue earlier than others.

**Comment by [ZOU Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28803/zou-lu/) on 2017-01-09**:
BTW, I hate `vtk`, they love to change things, always like playing a solo

**Comment by [alphayed](https://answers.ros.org/users/28904/alphayed/) on 2017-01-09**:
I hear you `vtk` has been causing me lots of issues during this build.